# Android: Change Selector font size based on theme / style

Tags: android, css-selectors

I am working on theming my application, and I would like to add effects to a listview item when it is selected.  While I have successfully accomplished theming the text color, I would also like to make changes to the text size itself while pressed.

Can I set this via code somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do that using a resource in say a style or a layout file:

This hasn't be tested for typos, etc...

Here's a quick example:

```
<resources>
    <!--  Theme Variables that can be used in any style, etc.. -->
    <attr name="branded_text_color" format="reference" />
    <attr name="branded_text_size"  format="reference" />
    <attr name="branded_background_color" format="reference" />
    <attr name="branded_icon_drawable"  format="reference" />

    <!-- Themes -->
    <style name="theme_alpha" parent="@android:Theme">
      <item name="branded_text_color">@color/alpha_text_color</item>
      <item name="branded_text_size">18sp</item>
      <item name="branded_background_color">@color/alpha_background_color</item>
      <item name="branded_icon_drawable">@drawable/alpha_icon</item>
    </style>
    <style name="theme_beta" parent="@android:Theme">
      <item name="branded_text_color">@color/beta_text_color</item>
      <item name="branded_text_size">24sp</item>
      <item name="branded_background_color">@color/beta_background_color</item>
      <item name="branded_icon_drawable">@drawable/beta_icon</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text Style -->
    <style name="title_font" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
       <item name="android:textColor">?branded_text_color</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">?branded_text_size</item>
       <item name="android:background">?branded_background_color</item>
       <item name="android:padding">10dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```